# How to solve this physics problem without a calculator (for an upcoming test)

Tags: physics

Ok so i am a student and i have bad time on high school physics

because i cant use calculator on an upcoming test

here is my problem
transfer from 5000 second to hour

now i can use calculator right now but i wont until i know how to transfer from second to hour

PS"i am from K S A so 100% that i well have hard time knowing the solution"**strong text**

Comment: Do you know that $1$ hour contains $3600$ seconds?

Answer (score 2):

$5000$ sec is $1$ hour and $1400$ secs. A quarter hour is $900$ sec. So $5000$ sec is one hour and one quarter hour, and $500$ seconds left. $500$ seconds is $8$ minutes and $20$ seconds left. So, we have here

$$5000 \text{ secs =}$$$$ 1\text{ hour}, 1 \text{ quarter hour }, 8 \text{ minutes, and } 20 \text{ seconds }$$
or$$1\text{ hour } ,23 \text{ minutes, and } 20 \text{ seconds}.$$

If this is the expected answer... Although, I don't think that they want the following answer
$$5000 \text{ secs } = 1.388888888888888888...\text{ hours}.$$

Comment: My edit was "hour" for "our" at the very start.............+1

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: THX.